# List my custom images Azure CLI

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli

I'm using Azure CLI to managed my VMs.
My VMs are created from a custom image. I forgot the name I was given to the image.
I created the image using `az image create`

Is there any way to list all my custom images name?

I tried using this command: `az vm image list -o table -g myGroup` but i got an exception that resource group parameter is not valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command will list all the images/name “azure vm image list”

**Azure CLI**

**For images, use az image list --resource-group**

Additional information: This article details some of the most common commands to [create and manage virtual machines (VMs).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/cli-manage)

Comment: This is giving my VMs. I'm looking for a command that will show my custom images. I edited the question

Comment: I have modified the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in getting a more simplified and readable response with the name of all your `Custom Images`, I would recommend this command:

`az image list --output table`

You can also use this command as mentioned in other answer:

`az image list --resource-group`

But, this command will give you a more detailed `JSON` response with information about `storageProfile`, `sourceVirtualmachine`, etc..